# Cloth worn around waist at the beach

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a noun that means the piece of cloth that some women wear around their waist when they are in bikini?

Comment: @Fattie Avoid answering questions in comments. Post comments here only to [ask for more information or suggest improvements](/help/privileges/comment). Other types of comment can be posted in the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or a chatroom created for the purpose.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Britain they are known variously as a ***sarong*** (from Malay national garment), ***pareo*** (from *pareu* - Tahitian national language, first used in English in 1769), ***kimono*** (from Japanese), or simply as ***wrap***, or  ***cover-up***. All those terms appear on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=pareo&tag=googhydr-21&index=clothing&hvadid=196753104943&hvpos=1t1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=15196667201515985619&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=e&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1006667&hvtargid=kwd-298351491255&ref=pd_sl_6a6r9cngo_e_p28)

The Marks & Spencers word seems to be ***sarong***, which suggests it is the more usual term in Britain. They don't seem to have heard of a ***pareo***.

[These are pictures of the real *Sarong Kebaya*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sarong+kebaya&num=50&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=cmswJKdcs2dXdM%253A%252CPVq3HG8QVb6x6M%252C_&usg=__YePJjt09ocZGmM6S7Cdm_T2_8p0%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibkqCJh-_YAhWD1IMKHXaVAPwQ9QEIODAC&biw=1366&bih=622#imgrc=cmswJKdcs2dXdM:) which is a Malay national dress. It is the uniform of the female flight attendants on both MAS (Malaysian Airlines) and SIA (Singapore Airlines). They are as different from beach wraps as are Japanese kimonos.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72362/discussion-on-answer-by-ws2-cloth-worn-around-waist-at-the-beach).

Answer (score 10):

In the US, I've never hear "pareo", only "sarong".  "Coverup" or "wrap" would work too (though "wrap" is more likely to refer to something that goes over your shoulders and arms).

Comment: *Pareo* is a common term in Hawaii (which is in the US)—possibly the most common term for the item, though not necessarily for the style of wearing it. That is, I can imagine saying "I can't decide whether to wear my new pareo sarong-style or toga-style."

Comment: Well, I'm American and I've heard pareo and sarong. Cover up is a generic term for some pretty awful outfits. Take a gander at this monstrosity: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/546835579741125424//ughhh. :)

Answer (score 4):

I would call it a [lavalava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavalava), particularly if worn by a Polynesian and definitely if it were a man wearing it.

Comment: For all that it is a correct answer, it's been a while since I heard this word in conversation, and in the mean time sarong has come up more often. All anecdote, of course.

Comment: @dmckee I live in New Zealand, so I probably hear it more than people who live where there isn't a numerous Samoan population.

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean a [**pareo**](https://www.google.nl/search?q=pareo&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik_66J3O3YAhUKJ8AKHethCOwQ_AUICigB&biw=1745&bih=885)?

Here's an example of one:

[image]

Comment: that actual item is listed as a "cover-up" or "wrap" or "scarve" on many sites, heh!  :)  (and yes, as a pareo and sarong on others)